# Does my C++ variable live on the stack or the heap?

Tags: c++, heap-memory, stack-memory

This is my first question on stack overflow. Apologies if this is a "dumb" question, but I'm currently learning C++, and I'm a little confused by something. As I understand it, in the code below, the variable "myVariable" is declared on the heap but instantiated in the constructor on the stack. So where does it "live" - on the heap or the stack?

```
class MyClass{
    int _myVariable;
    MyClass(int i){
        _myVariable = i;
    }
}
```

Comment: In this code it isn’t declared on any storage. It’s just a blueprint of a class. It depends on how you instantiate it where it goes. (And probably environment, I don’t think the standard defines things like stack and heap, it’s just how things are pretty much always done). If you create an instance of this class in the heap, all of it is in the heap. If you instantiate it in the stack, all of it is in the stack (in *this* case since there is no allocations specified)

Comment: It lives wherever the `MyClass` variable lives. If you use `new MyClass` it will be in the heap. If you declare a local variable it will be in the stack. If you declare a global variable it will be in the data segment.

Comment: Generally speaking there are no stack and heap; those are implementation details. Some systems have no stack and some have no heap.  My advice would be to not try and categorize variables in those terms.   Instead there is the variable's lifetime and storage class ; which for non-static class members is the same as that of an object of that class.

Comment: @M.M: no stack ? Wow !

Comment: @M.M There are, however, "Automatic Storage" and "Dynamic Storage " :P

Comment: new usese memory heap

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ `new` uses dynamic memory, which MAY use a memory heap. That is an implementation detail.

Answer (score 6):

The member variable is allocated according to how class is instantiated.

```
void example() {
  MyClass a{17}; // This allocates memory on stack
  MyClass *b = new MyClass(17); // This allocates memory on heap
}
```

Comment: I've added a function because `a` looked like a global variable, which typically is neither on the stack nor on the heap.

Answer (score 5):

"Stack" and "Heap" are implementation details. The C++ standard defines `Automatic Storage` and `Dynamic Storage`.
The most common implementations for the storage of variables are stack and heap, respectively.

The `new` operator makes an object live on the dynamic storage:

`MyClass* mc = new MyClass(14);`.
Note how we now need to use a pointer to access it.

With automatic storage, we can omit the pointer semantics:

`MyClass mc = MyClass(14); // constructs an object on the automatic storage`.

The object lifetime is managed - you've guessed - automatically. More precisely until the **end of the scope**.

With dynamically allocated objects, you have to manage the lifetime of the objects yourself.

There are cases where you can't use automatic storage: Namely polymorphism.

If `MyClass` is polymorphic (that means, it has virtual functions), you can't put it into the automatic storage since the compiler needs to know the size of an object. Since with polymorphism, the size of the pointed-to object can change at runtime it's not possible to create it on the automatic storage.

```
MyClass c = MyClass2(); //Object Slicing 
c.foo(); // calls MyClass::foo()

MyClass* cc = new MyClass2(); //No Object Slicing
cc->foo(); // calls MyClass2::foo();
```

There are helper classes that take away the responsibility to clean up your memory:
`unique_ptr` and `shared_ptr` (although the latter is used rarely).

Comment: Just one more the given code is just a "class declaration", nothing will be aloocated.

Comment: The "If MyClass is polymorphic" part is misleading. You can absolutely put `MyClass` objects in automatic storage, and you even show you can. And the "size of an object can change at runtime" is wrong; an object has the same size from the start of its lifetime to its end. I understand what you mean, but I'm not your target audience.

Comment: @MSalters read again: I wrote `the pointed-to object's size`, not `the object's size can change`. Also the `MyClass c` is NOT polymorphic, even though I try to instantiate `MyClass2` since it calls `MyClass::foo()` and not `MyClass2::foo()`

Comment: @Raildex: ISO C++: "11.7.3 Virtual functions : A class with a virtual member function is called a _polymorphic class._". If `MyClass::foo` is `virtual`, then `MyClass` is polymorphic. That you can slice `MyClass2` does not matter; whether a class is polymorphic is determined solely by what the standard says.

Comment: @MSalters I completely missed that. I will edit my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

In the given code, nothing is allocated, you have a mere class declaration.

It is contradictory (and wrong) that "myVariable" is declared on the heap while instantiated in the constructor on the stack.

A simple constructor like yours does no allocation, it just assigns value upon creation of a class instance. Constructors do not allocate the instance, destructors do not deallocate it.

The allocation being done on the heap or on the stack will depend on how you use the class (as a plain variable or with a pointer).

Answer (score 3):

It depends on where does the object live. If the actual object is on the heap the variable also lives on the heap. If the object lives on the stack the variable also lives on the stack.

Look at this example:

```
MyClass myObject = MyClass(5); // myObject lives on the stack and thus the variable i for myObject also lives on the stack
    
MyClass* newObject = new MyClass(5); // newObject is allocated on the heap and the variable i for newObject lives on the heap
    
delete newObject; // since newObject is created using new we must free the memory after use
```